# Can't find module inside of my folder (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, npm-start

As said in the title, I am using discord.js.
Shown below is the error I receive from my console when I try to run `npm run start`.

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './src/commands/clear.js'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\nicod\OneDrive\Desktop\CloudHostedBotCSCS\src\Bot.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:919:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:763:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:991:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\nicod\OneDrive\Desktop\CloudHostedBotCSCS\src\Bot.js:7:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1102:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1131:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:967:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:807:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\nicod\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\CloudHostedBotCSCS\\src\\Bot.js'
  ]
}
```

A screenshot of the console will look like this:
[Screenshot of console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkDVB.png)

Here is the block of code with the problem:

```js
const clear = require("./src/commands/clear.js");

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync("./src/commands/").filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./src/commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
```

The part with the problem is `const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./src/commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));`. It keeps saying that the module for `./src/commands/` can't be found.

Here is a screenshot of my files: [Screenshot of files + folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VFMU.png)

No matter how much I tweak my code I still receive this error any ideas why?

Comment: It seems your `Bot.js` file is already in `src` folder? Have you tried with `./commands/clear.js`?

Comment: will try that. thanks

Comment: did you try  `fs.readdirSync(__dirname+"/src/commands/")` ?

Comment: will try it now

Comment: that didnt work but i tweaked it and ```fs.readdirSync(__dirname+"/commands/")``` worked. thanks for the help

Comment: got the cde fixed thx

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in `Bot.js` file . that is in `src` directory.

then import should be `require('./commands/clear.js')` rather then `require('./src/commands/clear.js')`.

Check directory tree.

Comment: i get this error ```Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir './commands/'```

Comment: you have set up your file tree incorrectly, try and have a main folder for your bot. Then put index.js and your commands folder in that folder. This way you will have no errors.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `fs.readdirSync('./src/commands/')`

@Dario suggested using `fs.readdirSync(__dirname+"/src/commands/")`, but that still did not work. So I tweaked the code and `fs.readdirSync(__dirname+"/commands/")` ended up being the solution.

Comment: This is the answer but i cant tick it btw